# how to change existing docker container option

Tags: docker

Let's say I just create a new container `docker container run --name ap -it alpine bash`, it will failed because there is no `bash` in alpine yet.

Then I do `docker container run --name ap -it alpine sh`, it works.

In `alpine`, I install `bash` with `apk add bash`.

Now I wish each time I start alpine (`docker container start -ai ap`), I direct go `bash` instead of `sh`.

Is there any way to change the command for `alpine` from `sh` to `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your own new container, based on `alpine`, and start using it. This is a way how the things are being done in `Docker`. somthing like:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk --update add bash
```

Then build you image:

```
docker build -t my-alpine .
```

And use:

```
docker run -it my-alpine /bin/bash -c 'echo Hello'
```